# Segmentation fault when calling "new" in c++?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, new-operator, allocation

I got segfault when trying to call "new" to create a pointer and push it into a vector. The code that I push the element in the vector is:

```
queue->push_back(new Box(gen_id, Interval(x_mid, x_end), Interval(y_mid-y_halfwidth, y_mid+y_halfwidth)));
```

Basically Box is a Class and the constructor just take 3 arguments, `generation_id`, and 2 `Intervals`. I printed out the content in vector before and after this "push", 
before:

```
[ -0.30908203125, -0.3087158203125 ] , [ -0.951416015625, -0.9510498046875 ]
[ -0.3087158203125, -0.308349609375 ] , [ -0.951416015625, -0.9510498046875 ]
[ -0.30908203125, -0.3087158203125 ] , [ -0.9510498046875, -0.95068359375 ]
[ -0.3087158203125, -0.308349609375 ] , [ -0.9510498046875, -0.95068359375 ]
```

after:

```
[ -0.30908203125, -0.3087158203125 ] , [ -0.951416015625, -0.9510498046875 ]
[ -0.3087158203125, -0.308349609375 ] , [ -0.951416015625, -0.9510498046875 ]
[ 8.9039208750109844342e-243, 6.7903818933216500424e-173 ] , [ -0.9510498046875, -0.95068359375 ]
[ -0.3087158203125, -0.308349609375 ] , [ -0.9510498046875, -0.95068359375 ]
[ -0.3087158203125, -0.308349609375 ] , [ -0.95123291015625, -0.95086669921875 ]
```

I have no clue why does this happen, but apparently, there's one element got corrupted. There's no other codes between these two sets of output except that "push", and I used gdb to confirm that. Also, I checked those 2 `Intervals` variables, both give me a result that make sense.

My questions is: in what situation does "new" get segfault? Or is my problem caused because of other stuff?  Thanks.

Comment: When does the segfault occur?  Please show us the code for `Box`.

Comment: Why are you pushing pointers?

Comment: I don't think new can normally segfualt.  I would look for stack corruption, starting with `Box(int, Interval, Interval)`, and `Interval(int, int)` and `Interval`s copy/move constructor/operator

Comment: @Moo, `new` can conceivably segfault if there is heap corruption.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: anything can happen if there is heap corruption.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766731/what-exactly-do-ib-and-ub-mean/2766749#2766749, so yes.  Still: probably array bounds or pointer errors.

Comment: Have you implemented correct copy constructors for Box and Interval ??

Comment: I was surprised that the segfault happened at the second time I do "push" (I have a total of 4 "pushes"). The first time it prints out the above wired result, and the second time it immediately throws segfault :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming it really is `new` generating the segfault, the most common cause would be a corrupted heap, typically a result of overwriting memory you don't own and/or a double delete.

Valgrind will be your friend if you can run on a Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that `new` itself is giving you the segfault; the problem is probably in one of the constructors. Try splitting up that giant line, and put in some print statements to see exactly where the problem is.

```
printf("Creating the first interval...\n");
Interval a(x_mid, x_end);
printf("Creating the second interval...\n");
Interval b(y_mid-y_halfwidth, y_mid + y_halfwidth);
printf("Creating the box...\n");
Box* box_to_enqueue = new Box(gen_id, a, b);
printf("Enqueueing the box...\n");
// Do you really want to enqueue a pointer instead of a Box?
queue->push_back(box_to_enqueue);
```

Comment: And don't forget to put an fflush() in this sequence, or else error messages might end up in an unwritten buffer. Even better, use a debugger.