# What is the difference between char array and char pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers in C but I am currently confused with the following:

- ```
  char *p = "hello"
  ```

  This is a char pointer pointing at the character array, starting at *h*.
- ```
  char p[] = "hello"
  ```

  This is an array that stores *hello*.

What is the difference when I pass both these variables into this function?

```
void printSomething(char *p)
{
    printf("p: %s",p);
}
```

Comment: This would not be valid: `char p[3] = "hello";` The initializer string is too long for the size of the array you declare. Typo?

Comment: Or just `char p[]="hello";` would suffice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: differences between char pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) True, this also asks specifically about the function parameter, but that is not `char` specific.

Comment: you need to understand they are fundamentally different. the only commonality in this is that the base of the arry p[] is a const pointer which enabled to access the array p[] via a pointer.
p[] itself holds memory for a string, whereas *p just points to address of first element of just ONE CHAR (ie., points to the base of already allocated string). 
To better illustrate this, consider below:
 char *cPtr = {'h','e','l','l','o', '\0'}; ==>this is an error,as cPtr is a pointer to only a character
 char cBuff[] = {'h', 'e','l','l','o','\0'}; ==>This is Ok, bcos cBuff itself is a char array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

`char*` and `char[]` *are different types*, but it's not immediately apparent in all cases. This is because arrays *decay into pointers*, meaning that if an expression of type `char[]` is provided where one of type `char*` is expected, the compiler automatically converts the array into a pointer to its first element.

Your example function `printSomething` expects a pointer, so if you try to pass an array to it like this:

```
char s[10] = "hello";
printSomething(s);
```

The compiler pretends that you wrote this:

```
char s[10] = "hello";
printSomething(&s[0]);
```

Comment: Is something changed from 2012 to now. For a character array "s" prints entire array.. i.e., "hello"

Comment: @BhanuTez No, how data is stored and what is done with the data are separate concerns. This example prints the entire string because that is how `printf` handles the `%s` format string: start at the address provided and continue until encountering null terminator. If you wanted to print just one character you could use the `%c` format string, for example.

Comment: Just wanted to ask whether `char *p = "abc";` the NULL character `\0` is automatically appended as in case of char [] array?

Comment: why i can set `char *name; name="123";` but can do the same with `int` type? And after using `%c` to print `name` , the output is unreadable string: `�`?

Answer (score 105):

Let's see:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *p = "hello";
    char q[] = "hello"; // no need to count this

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(p)); // => size of pointer to char -- 4 on x86, 8 on x86-64
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(q)); // => size of char array in memory -- 6 on both

    // size_t strlen(const char *s) and we don't get any warnings here:
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(p)); // => 5
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(q)); // => 5

    return 0;
}
```

foo* and foo[] are different types and they are handled differently by the compiler (pointer = address + representation of the pointer's type, array = pointer + optional length of the array, if known, for example, if the array is statically allocated), the details can be found in the standard. And at the level of runtime no difference between them (in assembler, well, almost, see below).

Also, there is a related [question](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html) in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/):

> **Q**: What is the difference between these initializations?
>
> ```
> char a[] = "string literal";   
> char *p  = "string literal";
> ```
>
> My program crashes if I try to assign a new value to p[i].
>
> **A**: A string literal (the formal term for a double-quoted string in C source) can be used in two slightly different ways:
>
> 1. As the initializer for an array of char, as in the declaration of char a[] , it specifies the initial values of the characters in that array (and, if necessary, its size).
> 2. Anywhere else, it turns into an unnamed, static array of characters, and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified. In an expression context, the array is converted at once to a pointer, as usual (see section 6), so the second declaration initializes p to point to the unnamed array's first element.
>
> Some compilers have a switch controlling whether string literals are writable or not (for compiling old code), and some may have options to cause string literals to be formally treated as arrays of const char (for better error catching).
>
> See also questions 1.31, 6.1, 6.2, 6.8, and 11.8b.
>
> References: K&R2 Sec. 5.5 p. 104
>
> ISO Sec. 6.1.4, Sec. 6.5.7
>
> Rationale Sec. 3.1.4
>
> H&S Sec. 2.7.4 pp. 31-2

Comment: In sizeof(q), why doesn't q decay into a pointer, as @Jon mentions in his answer?

Comment: @garyp q doesn't decay into a pointer because sizeof is an operator, not a function (even if sizeof was a function, q would decay only if the function was expecting a char pointer ).

Comment: thanks, but printf("%u\n" instead of printf("%zu\n" , I think you should remove z.

Answer (score 60):

> What is the difference between char array vs char pointer in C?

**C99 N1256 draft**

There are two different uses of character string literals:

1. Initialize `char[]`:

   ```
   char c[] = "abc";
   ```

   This is "more magic", and described at 6.7.8/14 "Initialization":

   > An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
   >   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
   >   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
   >   elements of the array.

   So this is just a shortcut for:

   ```
   char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
   ```

   Like any other regular array, `c` can be modified.
2. Everywhere else: it generates an:

   - unnamed
   - array of char [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-c)
   - with static storage
   - that gives UB (undefined behavior) if modified

   So when you write:

   ```
   char *c = "abc";
   ```

   This is similar to:

   ```
   /* __unnamed is magic because modifying it gives UB. */
   static char __unnamed[] = "abc";
   char *c = __unnamed;
   ```

   Note the implicit cast from `char[]` to `char *`, which is always legal.

   Then if you modify `c[0]`, you also modify `__unnamed`, which is UB.

   This is documented at 6.4.5 "String literals":

   > 5 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
   >   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character
   >   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
   >   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
   >   type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
   >   sequence [...]
   >
   > 6 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
   >   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
   >   undefined.

6.7.8/32 "Initialization" gives a direct example:

> EXAMPLE 8: The declaration
>
> ```
> char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines "plain" char array objects `s` and `t` whose elements are initialized with character string literals.
>
> This declaration is identical to
>
> ```
> char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
> t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
> ```
>
> The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration
>
> ```
> char *p = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines `p` with type "pointer to char" and initializes it to point to an object with type "array of char" with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use `p` to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.

**GCC 4.8 x86-64 ELF implementation**

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s = "abc";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and decompile:

```
gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -c main.c
objdump -Sr main.o
```

Output contains:

```
 char *s = "abc";
8:  48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
f:  00 
        c: R_X86_64_32S .rodata
```

Conclusion: GCC stores `char*` it in `.rodata` section, not in `.text`.

If we do the same for `char[]`:

```
 char s[] = "abc";
```

we obtain:

```
17:   c7 45 f0 61 62 63 00    movl   $0x636261,-0x10(%rbp)
```

so it gets stored in the stack (relative to `%rbp`).

Note however that the default linker script puts `.rodata` and `.text` in the same segment, which has execute but no write permission. This can be observed with:

```
readelf -l a.out
```

which contains:

```
 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   02     .text .rodata
```

Comment: @leszek.hanusz Undefined Behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766731/what-exactly-do-ib-and-ub-mean Google "C language UB" ;-)

Answer (score 11):

You're not allowed to change the contents of a string constant, which is what the first `p` points to. The second `p` is an array initialized with a string constant, and you *can* change its contents.

Answer (score 9):

For cases like this, the effect is the same: You end up passing the address of the first character in a string of characters.

The declarations are obviously not the same though.

The following sets aside memory for a string and also a character pointer, and then initializes the pointer to point to the first character in the string.

```
char *p = "hello";
```

While the following sets aside memory just for the string. So it can actually use less memory.

```
char p[10] = "hello";
```

Comment: http://codeplusplus.blogspot.com/2007/09/char-pointer-versus-char-array.html "However, initializing the variable takes a huge performance and space penalty for the array"

Comment: @leef: I think that depends where the variable is located. If it's in static memory, I think it is possible for the array and data to be stored in the EXE image and not require any initialization at all. Otherwise, yes, it certainly can be slower if the data has to be allocated and then the static data has to be copied in.

Answer (score 7):

From *APUE*, Section 5.14 :

```
char    good_template[] = "/tmp/dirXXXXXX"; /* right way */
char    *bad_template = "/tmp/dirXXXXXX";   /* wrong way*/
```

> ... For the first template, the name is allocated on the stack, because we use an
>   array variable. For the second name, however, we use a pointer. In this case, only the
>   memory for the pointer itself resides on the stack; the compiler arranges for the string to
>   be stored in the read-only segment of the executable. When the `mkstemp` function tries
>   to modify the string, a segmentation fault occurs.

The quoted text matches @Ciro Santilli 's explanation.

Comment: It is put on stack only if it is local variable, i,e, declared inside function body, otherwise it will be in .data section.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can remember, an array is actually a group of pointers.
For example

```
p[1]== *(&p+1)
```

is a true statement

Comment: I would describe an array as being a pointer to the address of a block of memory. Hence why `*(arr + 1)` brings you to the second member of `arr`. If `*(arr)` points to a 32-bit memory address, e.g. `bfbcdf5e`, then `*(arr + 1)` points to `bfbcdf60` (the second byte). Hence why going out of the scope of an array will lead to weird results if the OS doesn't segfault. If `int a = 24;` is at address `bfbcdf62`, then accessing `arr[2]` might return `24`, assuming a segfault doesn't happen first.

Answer (score 2):

`char p[3] = "hello"` ? should be `char p[6] = "hello"` remember there is a '\0' char in the end of a "string" in C.

anyway, array in C is just a pointer to the first object of an adjust objects in the memory. the only different s are in semantics. while you can change the value of a pointer to point to a different location in the memory an array, after created, will always point to the same location.
also when using array the "new" and "delete" is automatically done for you.

Answer (score 0):

### It looks the same but there are subtle differences.

This declaration of an `char` array:

```
char p[] = "hello"
```

It means `p` is a **unmodifiable lvalue**, and you can use `p` as an alias to this array. In fact you can use `p` just as an address of the array (or the first element of an array): `p` is an alias for `&p[0]`

But you can't operate on it like you can on pointers, you cannot change its value:

```
p++;
```

But you can get its value:

```
printf("Address of 3rd character:%p:", (p + 2));
```

As all initialized (global) variables, it will be put in `.data` section of a ELF file:

```
Hex dump of section '.data':
  0x00004000 00000000 00000000 08400000 00000000 .........@......
  0x00004010 68656c6c 6f00                       hello.

    ...
```

In this case we declare char pointer and initialize it too:

```
    char *p = "hello"
```

But string literal used for initialization will be put in .`rodata` section while char pointer itself will be in `.data` section
of ELF file:

```
Hex dump of section '.rodata':
  0x00002000 01000200 68656c6c 6f00              ....hello.
```

Comment: _"It means `p` is a unmodifiable lvalue, and you can use `p` as an alias to this array..... `p` is an alias for `&p[0]`."_ -- This has a couple of problems. First, `p` is the array, not an alias, and `p` is not an alias for `&p[0]`. Rather, `p` _decays_ to a pointer equivalent to `&p[0]` in most expressions. `p` is an lvalue that is not modifiable, as you say, but when `p` decays to a pointer the resulting pointer is _not_ an lvalue (6.3.2.1 §3). This is the reason that `p++` fails to compile; `++` requires an lvalue operand.