# Difference between char array[100] and char *array when calling functions?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion, palindrome

i'd like to know why this code works fine with `char tab[100]` but doesn't work if I use `char *tab` ? fgets function takes a `char*` array as a parameter right ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 Int Palindrome(char* str, int i, int j);

 int main()
{
    char tab[100];
    printf("Enter your string : \n");
    fgets(tab, 100, stdin); 
    int j = strlen(tab);
    printf("%d\n", Palindrome(tab, 0, j - 2));
    return 0;
}

int Palindrome(char* str, int i, int j)
{
    if (i >= j)
    {
        printf("My word is a Palindrome !\n");
        return printf("<(^w^)>\n");
    }
    else if (str[i] != str[j])
    {
        printf("My word is not a Palindrome !\n");
        return printf("<(X.X)>\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        return Palindrome(str, i + 1, j - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is that `char tab` thingy?

Comment: It will work with `char *tab= malloc(100);`

Comment: "doesn't work" How? What error did you get? Where is this `char *tab` declared? Did you ever bother to allocate memory for it? Put more effort into asking a usable question.

Comment: What do you mean "but doesn't work if I use char *tab " ? Have you allocated your string?

Comment: An array always has actual storage space, (neglecting the trivial [0]), a pointer does not.  They are different things, so it's not surprising that one will work when the other does not, (or invokes UB).

Comment: Read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C textbook.

Comment: It was a massive error to allow passing arrays by implicit pointer.  C would have been a much better language if array passing required an explicit address operator, eg 'Palindrome(&tab, 0, j - 2)', (or indeed, an actual 'real' string type with a length, but that's another ball of wibbly-wobbly).  Now we're stuck with this 'arrays and pointers are the same' fallacy that has to continually explained away:(  It's fairly clear that Dennis was on tequila when defining this language feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Char array vs char pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

With "not work" you probably mean you get some serious error reported like a segmentation fault.

The difference between `char tab[100]` and `char *tab` is that the first has storage allocated and the second hasn't. When you call a function with an array as a parameter, then the compiler passes a pointer to the first element of the array, so for the function that got called it doesn't see the difference whether it is called with an array-parameter or with a pointer-parameter.

So to let your program work with `char *tab;` you must first allocate storage to this pointer, such as with `char *tab=malloc(100);` Now that there is valid storage allocated (and the pointer now points to it), you can call your function with this `tab` as parameter.