# How to update char monthName[256];

Tags: c++

My assignment is to create a calendar when the user enters a month and year. All of that is working great, but I can't figure out how to update a `char monthName[256];` variable. My guess is `monthName = "January"` (or whichever month), but that doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

FWIW, the user doesn't enter the month name. I have to print it to the screen based on the month number the user enters.

Comment: If you use `std::string` instead of `char []` you could use `monthName = "January"`

Comment: If you for some unknown reason must use `char[]` use [`sprintf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) or [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) or `strncpy`.

Comment: It is reasonable to believe he has to use C types. It's a *intro to Computer Science* class. It's believable that they are just studying C currently before advancing to C++ enhancements.

Comment: Whoa! Lots of hate here. Why all the downvotes? What? Noobs aren't allowed to ask questions?

Comment: You're right, @YotamSalmon. We're just getting started. C vs. C++ is greek to me at this point. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: @Scott Welcome. When I used to teach intro to CS using C, I too used C++ compilers for my students and did not make the distinction between the two. So it's understandable.

Comment: Even if they are "learning C", chances are the university or textbook is presenting it as C++ and it is fundamental to career success that the difference be learned and be learned early.

Use std::string for text in C++ unless your teacher explicitly prohibits it, and even then ask why it is being prohibited. Later on, you might go c-style string or std::string depending on performance requirements or if you have some requirement for a fixed memory size or something. But do, learn what "C-style string" means, how to use it, and how to use "std::string" on day one!

Comment: @Scott it's usually not a very productive idea to *guess* what you can or should do. I would recommend that you ask your instructor to teach you how arrays can be modified - surely they must do so before they ask you to do an assignment where you need to modify an array.

Comment: You would think. Believe me, there has been a lot of complaining from the class due to the inadequate textbook material.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `std::string` instead, such as `std::string monthName = "Jan"; monthName = "Feb";`.

If there is some reason you must use C-style strings, then `std::strcpy` will solve your problem. Such as `std::strcpy(monthName,"Jan");`, which will copy the string "Jan" into the character array. You cannot assign a character string directly to an array like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to change the address of the string `monthName` by design, it's constant in C/C++. You can't change the variable, but only its indexes (`monthName[0] = 'J'` would work).

You can read more about how string literals and how char arrays are saved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c)

Comment: 1. this is not C, and 2. arrays are not pointers in C nor in C++.

Comment: I believe C and C++ are no different in the matter I wrote (char arrays), although I did miss the fact he wrote C++. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642423/3873323) is what I meant when said pointer. Of course the term "address" is more accurate.