# C programming array of characters or string as function parameter

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

If I for example define an array

```
char string[20] = "something";
```

And function

```
void f(char* somestring[])
```

What is this, an address or a number or what and how can I work with this? In which purposes is it used?

Comment: `string` is an *array* of 20 `char`s.  `somestring` is a *pointer* to a pointer to a `char`.

Comment: See [What is the difference between char array vs char pointer in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c), and [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer).

Comment: The last part of the question is much too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an address is a number. Then, type `char *foo[]` (which really is just `char **foo`) has several **equivalent** interpretations.

1. `foo` is a doubly indexed `char` array.
2. `foo` is a pointer to a `char` array (that is, a string if it's null terminated like a string literal is).
3. and probably the rarest use case, `foo` is a pointer, to a pointer to a `char` value.

It can be used in several ways as well.

1. `foo` is a char 2-dimensional array ; then `foo[x][y]` retrieves you the character in the array at row `x` and column `y`.
2. `foo` is a pointer to a string. Then `(*foo)[x]` gives you the `x`-th character of the string.
3. Use `**foo` to set the `char` value, and `*foo` to change the character pointed to by the pointer.

**EDIT**: of course, all these are composeable and equivalent. For instance, `foo[0][0]` is just `(*foo)[0]` which is just `**foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a 20-element array of `char` - you can store a *string* of up to 19 characters (need to reserve one element for the string terminator), or you can store a sequence of 20 characters that does *not* represent a string (like a hash value or something).

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

So, if you passed `string` as an argument to a function, like so:

```
f( string );
```

what the function actually receives is a pointer value:

```
void f( char *somestring ) { ... }
```

In the context of a function parameter declaration (and *only* in that context), `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both treated as `T *a`, so you could declare `f` to be any of

```
void f( char somestring[20] ) { ... }
```

or

```
void f( char somestring[] ) { ... }
```

as well.

The subscript operator `[]` is defined to work on pointer expressions as well as array expressions, so you can still use `[]` to index into `somestring` like any other array:

```
void f( char *somestring )
{
  int i = 0;
  while ( somestring[i++] )
  {
    // do something interesting with somestring[i]
  }
}
```

So, if `void f( char *somestring )` is the same as `void f( char somestring[] )`, then what do we make of

```
void f( char *somestring[] )
```

?

In this case, it's clear that `somestring` is meant to be an array of *pointers to* `char`, something like

```
char *strings[] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch", ... };
```

Each `strings[i]` stores the *address* of the corresponding string literal, not the contents of the string itself.  By the same rule above, the prototype may also be written as

```
void f( char **somestring ) { ... }
```

or

```
void f( char *somestring[N] ) { ... }
```

The one thing `somestrings` is *not* in this case is a 2D array of `char`.  If `strings` had been declared

```
#define N ... // number of strings
#define M ... // maximum length of string

char strings[N][M+1] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch", ... };
```

then, if we pass `strings` to `f`, it would "decay" to

```
void f( char (*somestrings)[M+1] ) { ... }
```

The the type of `strings` is "N-element array of M+1-element array of `char`", so the expression "decays" to "pointer to M+1-element array of `char`".