# C: How to implement argv into variable and implement for loop?

Tags: c, function, arguments, func

I am working on creating an uppercase function for practice. I want to implement argc and argv arguments with for loop for checking each input values in to my code but When use argv like that it wont work:

> char s[] = argv[0];

But this is working:

> uppercase(argv[1]);

How can I implement my arguments into variable with for loop?

Here is my code;

Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "upperc.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[] = argv[1]; // This is giving me a error.

    printf("%s \n", uppercase(argv[1])); // This is working

    return 0;
}
```

upper.c:

```
/*
Parsing the string, then making the letters to uppercase.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include "upperc.h"

#define MAGIC_NUMBER 32 //6th bit ability of letter chars

char * uppercase(char *s) {
    for(char *p = s; *p; ++p) {
        if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z')
            *p = *p - MAGIC_NUMBER;
    }

    return s;
}
```

upper.h:

```
#ifndef UPPERC_H_INCLUDED
#define UPPERC_H_INCLUDED

char * uppercase(char *s);

#endif // UPPERC_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: `uppercase(argv(1));` is *not* working, and doesn't match what is in your code.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error is: Invalid initializer

Comment: also i put codeblocks argumets tab some strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**case 1**

`char s[] = argv[0];` here `s` is an array and `argv[0]` is a pointer or address.

You cannot store some pointer in an array

Instead use `char *cmd_arg = argv[0];`

If you want to read set of command line arguments use loops to iterate over set of command line inputs

```
//since argv[0] indicates program name , starting `a` from 1 instead of 0
for(int a = 1; a < argc; a++)
    uppercase(argv[a]);
```

**case 2**

`uppercase(argv(1));` i think you mean by `uppercase(argv[1]);`

That is fine because `uppercase` is accepting a pointer `char*`

Comment: well yes string type char how to i store in a variable then ?

Comment: Is there any other way without using cmd arg ? I need to work with argv because I have setup arguments in tab bunch of strings, I need the use argv and pass into uppercase one by one!

Answer (score 1):

you should use a char pointer instead of a char array:

```
char *s = argv[1];
```

See this for reference : [What is the difference between char array and char pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-and-char-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1]` is not a char array. It's a pointer to the char array. So you need to assign char s like this:

```
char *s = argv[1];
```

Also, you can use `malloc` with `memcpy` from `stdlib.h` and `strlen` from `string.h` to copy `argv[1]` to `s` (recommended if you want to do some modifications with `s` later):

```
size_t len = strlen(argv[1]))+1; // 1 for NULL byte
char *s = malloc(len);
memcpy(s, argv[1], len);
```

The advantage of second approach is ability to `realloc`ate memory later.