# How to make char **arr in c?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

**This is the typical c code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
}
```

**I wanted to make like this **argv array. But I got error. How can I make an array like this. Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **names = {"Prite", "Ridoy", "Ridhita"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", names[i]);
    }
}
```

**I got this error:**

```
$ make pointers
pointers.c:6:21: error: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'char [6]' [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    char **names = {"Prite", "Ridoy", "Ridhita"};
                    ^~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: pointers] Error 1
```

Comment: Here is the source for gcc: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/argv.c - you could just call buildargv() with "Prite Ridoy Ridhita"

Comment: All you need is this:  `char *names[] = {"Prite", "Ridoy", "Ridhita"};`  If you want it to be `NULL`-terminated (like `argv`), then add a `NULL` to the end of the initializer list.  You want `names` to be an array.  Don't use the anonymous array syntax shown above, *unless* you really want `names` to be a pointer that you can modify.  Note that a `char *[]` will "decay" into a `char **` when passed as a function argument (among other things).

Comment: I tried it what you have told but I there is a question came in mind that "char  *names[]" is working but "char **names" is not but the case of argv is working.

Comment: @RidoyDey `argv` works because when `main` is called, an array is created to hold the pointers to the arguments.  That array effectively has type `char *[]`.  But when passed to `main`, it "decays" to type `char **` (just as an `int []` array is passed as `int *`).  In fact, in your declaration of `main`, you can use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and it will work the same as if you had used `char **argv`.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `char**` is a pointer to a `char*` (string), and not an array of `char*`.

It may sound confusing since `char*` looks the same as `char[]`, so `char**` should be the same as `char[][]`, right? Actually, no.

See: [What is the difference between char array and char pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187933/13959383)

**Internally** they are treated as different types. In this example, `char**` is a **pointer to a string literal** and not an array of string literals.

The correct line would be

```
char *names[] = {"Prite", "Ridoy", "Ridhita"};
```

Comment: These are string literals, so ideally you should have array of pointers to _const_ char.

Comment: @hyde, yes but see [the rationale for `char*[]` in the Posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html#tag_16_111_08). (Look for the paragraph which starts "The statement about argv[] and envp[] being constants...")