# In this solution, if *inputString is a memory address (and the input is a char type) then does *inputString qualify as an array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, null-terminated

I was solving a challenge on CodeSignal in C. Even though the correct libraries where included, I couldn't use the strrev function in the IDE, so I looked up a similar solution and modified it to work. This is good. However, I don't understand the distinction between a literal string and an array. Reading all this online has left me a bit confused. If C stores all strings as an array with each character terminated by \0 (null terminated), how can there be any such thing as a literal string? Also if it is the case that strings are stored as an array, **would inputString store the address of the array or is it an array itself* of all the individual characters stored.

Thanks in advance for any clarification provided!

Here is the original challenge, C:
Given the string, check if it is a palindrome.

```
bool solution(char * inputString) {
    // The input will be character array type, storing a single character each terminated by \0 at each index
    // * inputString is a pointer that stores the memory address of inputString. The memory address points to the user inputted string
    // bonus: inputString is an array object starting at index 0
    // The solution function is set up as a Boolean type ("1" is TRUE and the default "0" is FALSE)
   int begin;
   // The first element of the inputString array is at position 0, so is the 'counter'
   int end = strlen(inputString) - 1;
   // The last element is the length of the string minus 1 since the counter starts at 0 (not 1) by convention
   while (end > begin) {
       if (inputString[begin++] != inputString[end--]) {
           return 0;
       }
   } return 1;
}
```

Comment: "each character terminated by \0" - this is incorrect. \0 is stored after the _last_ character, so e.g. "foo" is stored as an array `[ 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0']`, and in your case `inputString` stores the address of the first character.

Comment: This post may clarify things for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-and-char-pointer-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

A string is also an array of symbols. I think that what you don't understand is the difference between a char pointer and a string. Let me explain in an example:

Imagine I have the following:

```
char str[20]="helloword";
```

str is the address of the first symbol of the array. In this case str is the address of h. Now try to printf the following:

```
printf("%c",str[0]);
```

You can see that it has printed the element of the addres that is 'h'.

If now I declare a char pointer, it will be poining to whatever char adress I want:

```
char *c_pointer = str+1;
```

Now print the element of c_pointer:

```
printf("%c",c_pointer[0]);
```

You can see that it will print 'e' as it is the element of the second adress of the original string str.

In addition, what `printf("%s", string)` does is to printf every elemet/symbol/char from the starting adress(string) to the end adress where its element is '\0'.

Comment: "str is the address of the first symbol of the array" No, `str` *is* the array. There are just a lot of cases where an array *decays* into a pointer to the first element, such as when passing it as an argument to a function or doing arithmetic on it. There are also cases where it doesn't. `sizeof(str)` is 20, not the size of a pointer. And `&str` is a `char (*)[20]` (a pointer to an char array of length 20), not a `char**`

Comment: you are right that sizeof(char) is not the size of a pointer as it is the size of the array (in that context str is not the adress of the first element of teh array okay). But, if I make: char **a = &str , what is the problem of that? I mean &str is not a pointer to a char pointer?

Comment: The problem comes if you try to assign to `*a`. With a valid assignment, it's fine: `char *s =  "hello"; char **a = &s; *a = "world";` (`s` now points to the string `"world"`). But if `a` actually points to an array, not a `char*`, things go wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/K86sKx7a6 (also note the compiler warning about the incompatible assignment)

Comment: I think that  a better definition would have been: "str is the array and it is pointing to the first element of the array, &str is the adress of the array (it can be a char** or a char(*)[SIZE] depending on the case" ) . Sounds better now?

Answer (score 0):

The linked question/answers in the comments pretty much cover this, but saying the same thing a slightly different way helps sometimes.

A string literal is a quoted string assigned to a `char` *pointer*.  It is considered *read only*.  That is, any attempts to modify it result in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  I believe that most implementations put string literals in read-only memory.  IMO, it's a shortcoming of C (fixed in C++) that a `const char*` type isn't required for assigning a string literal.  Consider:

```c
int main(void)
{
  char* str = "hello";
}
```

`str` is a string literal.  If you try to modify this like:

```c
#include <string.h>
... 

str[2] = 'f'; // BAD, undefined behavior
strcpy(str, "foo"); // BAD, undefined behavior
```

you're broken the rules.  String literals are read *only*.  In fact, you should get in the habit of assigning them to `const char*` types so the compiler can warn you if you try to do something stupid:

```c
const char* str = "hello"; // now you should get some compiler help if you
                           // ever try to write to str
```

In memory, the string "hello" resides somewhere in memory, and `str` points to it:

```c
str
  |
  |
  +-------------------> "hello"
```

If you assign a string to an *array*, things are different:

```c
int main(void)
{
  char str2[] = "hello";
}
```

`str2` is *not* read only, you are free to modify it as you want.  Just take care *not* to exceed the buffer size:

```c
#include <string.h>
...

str2[2] = 'f'; // this is OK
strcpy(str2, "foo"); // this is OK
strcpy(str2, "longer than hello"); // this is _not_ OK, we've overflowed the buffer
```

In memory, `str2` is an *array*

```
str2 = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '0', '\0' }
```

and is present right there in automatic storage.  It doesn't point to some string elsewhere in memory.

In most cases, `str2` can be used as a `char*` because in C, in most contexts, an array will *decay* to a pointer to it's first element.  So, you can pass `str2` to a function with a `char*` argument.  One instance where this is *not* true is with `sizeof`:

```c
sizeof(str) // this is the size of pointer (either 4 or 8 depending on your
            // architecture). If _does not matter_ how long the string that
            // str points to is
sizeof(str2) // this is 6, string length plus the NUL terminator.
```