# Initialize a container that is a private member variable of a class

Tags: c++, list, initialization, initializer, c++03

I have a `list<string> myList` as a private attribute of my class. The content of this list is known at compile time and is constant. Is there any compact way (in C++03) to initialize its value? I can only think of this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
myList.push_back(string("str1"));
myList.push_back(string("str2"));
myList.push_back(string("str3"));
etc.
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass():list("str1","str2","str3",etc.){
}
```

Comment: What you want to have is [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which is only available since C++11.

Comment: You could use hacks like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html :)

Comment: You can define a global array of your strings and use list's two iterator constructor:

`std::string arr[3] = { "str1", "str2", "str3" };

MyClass::MyClass() : myList(arr, arr+3)
{ }`

Comment: don't use `std::list` except for very specific circumstances.  If you don't know what those are, don't use `std::list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is not fully tested, but I would suggest this if you can't use the new and cool stuff in C++11:

```
class MyClassCreator
{
    MyClass result;
public:
    MyClassCreator(std::string param)
    {
        result.myList.push_back(param);
    }

    MyClassCreator& operator()(std::string param)
    {
        result.myList.push_back(param); 
        return *this;
    }

    operator MyClass() { return result; }

};
```

Usage:

```
MyClass c = MyClassCreator("object1")("object2")("object3");
```

### EDIT

See full example at http://ideone.com/LWGRCc

Comment: Cute and clever, for which I +1, but I don't much care for this and would shoot any programmer that did this in production code.  Its a little too clever to be maintainable.

Comment: @JohnDibling boost has this in their library.  It can be optimized very well, especially in C++11 (which is funny because then you have a better way through initializer lists). Although it is a sort of "factory" method, it is a little clever to be used in production code.

Answer (score 4):

I tend do do something like this:

```
static const string my_strs[] =
{
  "str1",
  "str2",
  "str3"
};

static const num_my_strs = sizeof(my_strs)/sizeof(my_strs[0]);
```

Then when it comes time to initialize the `list`:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
:  myList(my_strs, my_strs + num_my_strs)
{
}
```

...or:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  copy( my_strs, my_strs+num_my_strs, back_inserter(myList));
}
```

There are pros and cons to this approach.  The obvious con is you now have 2 copies of your data.  This also raises the question, if you know the contents at compile-time and they never change, do you even need the `list` at all?  Why not just use the `static const` array?

On the pro side, the code to initialize the list is a 1-liner, and never needs to change even if you change the compile-time constant data that's being coped in to the list.

**Edit:**  You can use standard library algorithms like `find` with plain old C-style arrays.  For example:

```
const string* it = std::find(my_strs, my_strs+num_my_strs, "str1");
if( it == (my_strs+num_my_strs) ) // functionally same as 'list.end()' eg, item not found
{ 
  // not found
}
else
{
  // found -- it points to item found
  string found_item = *it;
}
```

**Edit2** Whether or not an expression like `int a[2]; &a[2];` is well-defined is being debated.  I have edited the pointer math above to use a method that is well-known to not evoke UB.

**Edit3** I've found the relevant passages in the Standard relating to this.  The above expression (`int a[2]; &a[2];`) is in fact Undefined Behavior.  I have already edited my answer to not use that method.  Thanks to @MooingDuck for bringing this up.

Comment: Looks nice, but the need to have two copies would increase my line count exponentially. I need list, because it has iterators and I need them to call std::find(from,to,val) on my list.

Comment: @user1459339:  Are you aware that you can use the std library algorithms with the C-style array I have above?  In fact, I did just that in the second example where I `copy`'ed from the array to the `list`.  You could easily use `find` with my array.

Comment: I hesitate to downvote you, but isn't `&my_strs[num_my_strs]` UB?  Since you have a raw array, why not use `myList(my_strs, my_strs+num_my_strs)`?

Comment: @JohnDibling: C++11(Jan2012) §8.3.4\6 "the subscript operator `[]` is interpreted in such a way that `E1[E2]` is identical to `*((E1)+(E2)).`" so `my_strs[num_my_strs]` _is_ dereferencing that pointer and thus is UB.  But `my_strs+num_my_strs` is not UB.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I did not know I can use the algorithms with C-style array. Thanks. +1. 
Please, tell me what does UB mean?:)

Comment: @user1459339 [What exactly do IB and UB mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766731/what-exactly-do-ib-and-ub-mean)

Comment: @JohnDibling: [According to the Lounge chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6137261#6137261) it's well formed in C, but undefined in C++.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  I've found the relevant listings in the Standard, and I'm now convinced that `int a[2]; &a[2];` is indeed Undefined Behavior.