# CppCon 2018, Nicolai Josuttis: Why are these interpreted as iterators?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17

Nicolai Josuttis' "The Nightmare of Initialization in C++" presentation at CppCon 2018 had, at one point, the following piece of code:

```
std::vector< std::string > v07 = {{ "1", "2" }};
```

Nicolai [said the following](https://youtu.be/7DTlWPgX6zs?t=2433) (transcription mine):

> The problem is, what happens here is, we interpret these two parameters as *iterators*. So these are iterators, so *this* is the beginning of the range, and *this* is the end of the range, and they should refer to the same range of *characters*; because characters convert implicitly to strings this will compile. If you're lucky, you'll get a coredump. If not, you've got a big problem.

He lost me there. Can somebody explain what is going on here, exactly, step by step?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Below code

```
std::vector< std::string > v07 = { { "1", "2" } };
```

is equivalent to

```
std::string s = {"1","2"}; // call string(const char*, const char*)
std::vector<std::string> v07 = {s}; // initializer list with one item
```

the issue is with

```
   s={"1","2"};
```

This calls `string(const char* start, const char* end)` constructor,
   but `start` and `end` must refer to the same string object.  *"1"* and *"2"* are two different objects, so it leads to UB.

Comment: What exactly does UB stand for?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766749/3729797 for UB, Undefined Behaviour