# regex_token_iterator attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to split a string with a regular expression in C++.  Here's the minimum repro:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string str("abc");
  std::string regex("b");
  std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::const_iterator> a(str.begin(), str.end(), std::regex(regex), -1);
}
```

This program gives me a compile error: *attempting to reference a deleted function*

```
error C2280: 'std::regex_token_iterator<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,char,std::regex_traits<char>>::regex_token_iterator(_BidIt,_BidIt,const std::basic_regex<char,std::regex_traits<char>> &&,int,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

But I feel like I've set it up correctly.  Why am I getting this error and what do I need to change to get it to compile?

I was working from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/filsinger/3910580) as an example, but I can't get it to compile either.

I'm building with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 15.8.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructor which takes `regex` as temporary object is deleted because 
iterator doesn't make a copy of `regex` but keeps reference to this object.
This deleted function is to **prevent from passing temporaries into iterator**.
If you passed temporary object into iterator, you would get dangling reference.

According to [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator):

```
regex_token_iterator( BidirectionalIterator a, BidirectionalIterator b,
                      const regex_type&& re,
                      int submatch = 0,
                      std::regex_constants::match_flag_type m =
                          std::regex_constants::match_default ) = delete;
```

so what you need to do is create regex as *L-value* object:

```
  std::string str("abc");
  std::string regex("b");
  std::regex r(regex);
  std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::const_iterator> a(
       str.begin(), str.end(), r, -1);
```

Regarding the link you posted, deleted overload which takes reference to R-value was introduced since C++14, in C++11 there is overload which takes `const regex_type& re` - so a temporary object of regex can be passed to ctor of iterator, but it leads to *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: I would have preferred that "undefined behaviour" was spelled out rather than being written as "UB".  I had to go look that up, and [so have others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766731/what-exactly-do-ib-and-ub-mean).