# Why did the range based 'for' loop specification change in C++17?

Tags: c++, for-loop, language-lawyer, c++17

I was looking over some ugly code (that was modifying the underlying sequence while iterating), and to explore the definition of the range-based `for` loop, I went to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

There I noticed something strange:

The range based `for` loop changed in C++17, but I do not see the reason for the change, and the code looks the same to me (just "refactored").
So the old one was:

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression;
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
  }
}
```

The new one is

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression;
  auto __begin = begin_expr;
  auto __end = end_expr;
  for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
  }
}
```

Why was this change made, and does it make any legal C++14 programs exhibit undefined behavior ([UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766731/what-exactly-do-ib-and-ub-mean)) in C++17?

Comment: @r3musn0x I think this is probably a broader question than the one you’ve linked to.

Comment: @Tim, I agree, however the accepted answer to that question is way more comprehensive and it covers both of them.

Comment: As an aside, it's against the C++ standard to name your locals with double underscores. https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Using

```
auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;
```

requires both `begin_expr` and `end_expr` to return the same type.  This means you cannot have a sentinel iterator type that is different from the beginning type.  Using

```
auto __begin = begin_expr ;
auto __end = end_expr ;
```

fixes that issue while proving full backwards compatibility with C++14.

Comment: It would be more logical to have this update together with Ranges, probably.  Iterator-sentinel ranges are still very restricted in C++17.

Comment: @L.F. IIRC ranges was originally slated to be in C++17, instead we got a TS since it wasn't quite ready.  We still need this if we want to use the ranges TS, or ranges-v3.

Comment: @L.F. Ranges are a library feature. There is range-v3 lib on github that served as the basis for standardization and it benefited from this standardiese change.

Comment: Including the feature in C++17 proper also allows programmers to implement their own sentinels (or similar) if desired, and can potentially allow bugs to be discovered before the associated library additions are ready, @L.F.

Answer (score 32):

It is explained later in the "notes":

> As of C++17, the types of the begin_expr and the end_expr do not have to be the same ...

and you can't have that with:

```cpp
auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;
```